# Burgers' Equation with Compactly Supported Initial Condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Let $u$ solve:

$$
u_t + u u_x = 0
$$
Prove that if the initial condition $u_0(x)$ is compactly supported, then $u$ is compactly supported at any future times.

I'm not sure how to prove this. I was going to use the fact that $u$ is present in the pde and perhaps leverage that fact to prove compact support for future times. Would I have to do this using the method of characteristics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $u_0(x)$ vanishes outside the interval $[x_L,x_R] $. The exact implicit solution to $u_t+uu_x=0$ is $u=u_0(x-ut)$ implying that $u=0$ if $(x-ut)$ is not in $[x_L,x_R]$. Sice $u$ is finite, this gives finite upper and lower bounds for any given $t$

Comment: How are the implicit solutions calculated? I assume it's through the use of characteristics.

Comment: In effect, yes.The characteristic equation says that $u$ is constant along lines moving with speed $u$. In other words, $u=f(x-ut)$. To match the initial data the function $f$ must be the same as the function $u_0$. For example if $u_0(x)=kx$ then $u=k(x-ut)$ and this can be solved to give the explicit solution $u=kx/(1+kt)$. provided $kt\le1$